# Maestro Da Vinci — Traducción en ingles

Tags: traducción

"Maestro Da Vinci, no hace falta que se presente, todo el mundo habla de Usted."

What would be the correct translation of "Maestro"?

> Professor Da Vinci

Or

> Master Da Vinci

Or

> Teacher Da Vinci

Comment: I'd say Master. He's not well known for his teaching skills. But if from the context you know that they were talking about some phase of his life where he was teaching, then go with that.

Comment: *master* is often translated as *maestro* and not necessarily in an academic aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*master* is often taken as *maestro*, but this can be used on different situations.

- I can see my father as a *master* and he didn't even go to the university or even went to some academic school.
- A *teacher* can also be considered a *master* since their students praise him/her because of his/her knowledge.
- The term *professor* is often used for university, so you wouldn't normally call *master* a *professor.*
- Even workers such as plumbers, electricians, builders, etc. are often called *masters*.

Basically, seen in a more general way, *master* is used as *maestro.*